# Get All Latest Records Using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I tried querying the database this way but it returns the error.

> latest() not found.

```
DailyReport::get()->latest()->paginate(10)
```

I want it to return all the DailyReports with pagination.

Answer (score 5):

The `latest()` method is short for `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`. You can achieve what you want by:

```
$latest_daily_reports = DailyReport::latest()->paginate(10);
```

You can also change the column `latest()` orders by.

```
->latest('your_column_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `get()`.

You should try `DailyReport::latest()->paginate(10)`