# Laravel Eloquent retrive all latest items

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on an inventory database. I have some warehouse and some product. an example database can be:

[image: Inventory]

Please have a look at the following code:

```
public function scopeOf($query, $warehouse, $product, $date = '')
{
    $date = ($date == '' ? Carbon::today() : $date);
    return $query
        ->where(
            [
                ['warehouse', $warehouse],
                ['product', $product],
            ])
        ->whereDate('updated_at', '<=', $date)
        ->orderByDesc('updated_at')->take(1);
}
```

with this function I can get leatest data of one product in one warehouse by:
`$data = Inventory::Of('w1', 'INJR')->get();`

I need to list all latest data of all warehouse.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266679/get-all-latest-records-using-laravel-eloquent) but it list according to date only. In my case, for each warehouse and product I need to
get newest row.

I'm using SqLite in dev mode with laravel 8.

**Update:**

Maybe my question is not cleare.
Here is a working function for my question

```
public function scopeOfList($query, $warehouseName = [], $productName = [], $date = '')
{
    $date = ($date == '' ? Carbon::today() : $date);
    $db = $query->select('product', 'warehouse')->get()->toArray();
    $products = array_unique(
        array_filter(
            array_map(function ($n) use ($productName) {
                return ($productName == [] || in_array($n['product'] ,$productName)? $n['product'] : null );
                },
                $db),
            'strlen')
    );
    $warehouses = array_unique(array_map(function ($n) use ($warehouseName)
    {
        return ($warehouseName == '' || in_array($n['warehouse'] ,$warehouseName)? $n['warehouse'] : null );

    }, $db));
    $data = [];
    foreach ($warehouses as $warehouse){
        foreach ($products as $product){
            $data[] = Inventory::
                where(
                    [
                        ['warehouse', $warehouse],
                        ['product', $product],
                    ])
                ->whereDate('updated_at', '<=', $date)
                ->orderByDesc('updated_at')->get()->first();
        }
    }
    $inventory = array_filter($data, 'strlen');
    sort($inventory);
    return $inventory;
}
```

**Uses:**

```
    //get one/more product from one/more warehouse
    //returns latest data only
    $data = Inventory::OfList(['w1', 'w2'], ['INJR']);
    //returns latest data available before 3 days
    $data = Inventory::OfList(['w1', 'w2'], ['INJR', 'TP'], Carbon::now()->subDays(3));

    //get one product from all warehouse
    //returns latest data only
    $data = Inventory::OfList([], ['INJR']);
    //returns latest data available before 3 days
    $data = Inventory::OfList([], ['INJR'], Carbon::now()->subDays(3));

    //get all product from one warehouse
    //returns latest data only
    $data = Inventory::OfList(['w1']);
    //returns latest data available before 3 days
    $data = Inventory::OfList(['w1'], [], Carbon::now()->subDays(3));

    //get all product from all warehouse
    //returns latest data only
    $data = Inventory::OfList();
    //returns latest data available before 3 days
    $data = Inventory::OfList([], [], Carbon::now()->subDays(3));
```

I just need to simplify `scopeOfList` function to make it flexible with large volume of data in `inventories` table. If i have 500 warehouse 500 products in each warehouse those update every day then for 1 years data my php memory will be exhosted and also it will take considarable time to execute.

Comment: You should group by warehouse & product

Comment: I tried, didn't work

Comment: In my case, for each warehouse and product I need to get newest row. Could you give an example of this? what have you currently got and what is your expected result?

Comment: @ Anurat Chapanond I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you can get latest record per warehouse and prodcut using `exists` based on provided `$date` filter as

```
select a.*
from products a
where updated_at <= :date
and exists (
    select 1 
    from products b
    where b.warehouse = a.warehouse
      and b.product = a.product 
      and b.updated_at <= :date
      group by 1
      having max(b.updated_at) = a.updated_at
)
```

Using query builder above SQL can be transformed as

```
DB::table('products as a')
    ->whereDate('a.updated_at', '<=', $date)
    ->whereExists(function ($query) use ($date){
       $query->select(DB::raw(1))
             ->from('products as b')
             ->whereDate('b.updated_at', '<=', $date)
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('b.warehouse = a.warehouse'))
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('b.product = a.product'))
             ->groupByRaw('1')
             ->havingRaw('max(b.updated_at) = a.updated_at')
             ;
    });
```

If you need the latest record per warehouse and product without specifying any `$date` then remove `->whereDate()` filter from both clauses

Update: Not sure for the rest of the code in which you are applying array filtering and mapping functions the products and warehouses collection but for your updated question you can omit the foreach loops for latest data and just use `whereIn` for products and warehouses in combination with `whereExists` clause

```
public function scopeOfList($query, $warehouseName = [], $productName = [], $date = '')
{
    $date = ($date == '' ? Carbon::today() : $date);
    $products = //...
    $warehouses = //...
    
    $query
        ->whereDate('a.updated_at', '<=', $date)
        ->whereIn('a.warehouse',$warehouses)
        ->whereIn('a.product',$products)
        ->whereExists(function ($query) use ($date){
           $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                 ->from('inventory as b')
                 ->whereDate('b.updated_at', '<=', $date)
                 ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.warehouse = b.warehouse'))
                 ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.prodcut = b.prodcut'))
                 ->groupByRaw('1')
                 ->havingRaw('max(b.updated_at) = a.updated_at')
                 ;
        });

    return $query;
}
$data = Inventory::from( 'inventory as a' )
                 ->OfList(['w1', 'w2'], ['INJR', 'TP'], Carbon::now()->subDays(3));
```

Comment: May be my question is not cleare. I have updated it. Please take a look. sorry for inconvinence.

Comment: @MasumNishat I have updated my answer please review

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried and a little bit more to go maybe. I got an error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING (SQL: select * from "inventories" as "a" where strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "a"."updated_at") <= cast(2021-02-25 as text) and "a"."warehouse" in (BD-KH-JH-MO-1, BD-KH-JH-MO-2) and "a"."product" in (INJR, TP) and exists (select 1 from "inventories" as "b" where strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "b"."updated_at") <= cast(2021-02-25 as text) and a.warehouse = b.warehouse and a.prodcut = b.prodcut having max(b.updated_at) = a.updated_at))`

Comment: @MasumNishat I have update my answer by adding `groupByRaw('1')`, SQL lite doesn't allow having clause to use as standalone, so I made a tweak

Comment: Do you know why `Inventory::from( 'inventory as a' )->OfList([$request->get('w')], [$id])->skip(5)->take(5)->get()` returns all data? it should return 5 data after first 5

Comment: @MasumNishat Can you please confirm that you are returning `$query` object from your scope ? not your transformed array or new variable other than `$query` ?

Comment: yes i'm returning `$query` not array. just like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

don't send a query parameter and delete the $query parameter and use

```
public function scopeOf($warehouse, $product, $date = '')
{
$date = ($date == '' ? Carbon::today() : $date);  // or instead Carbon::today() by date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
$query=DB::table('Inventory')
    ->where('warehouse','$warehouse')
    ->where('product','$product')
    ->where('updated_at','<=','$data')
    ->orderBy('updated_at','DESC')
    ->take(1)
    ->get();

return $query;
}
```

Comment: why you use scope if you delete the query. It's very not recommended

Comment: May be my question is not cleare. I have updated it. Please take a look. sorry for inconvinence.